# PHP array_shift_recursive()

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do an equivalent to array_shift_recursive() and apparently my google ans SO search fails me.:

Take the following multi-dimension array continaing strings:

```
$array = [
   'shift6th'    => [
      'shift3rd' => [
         'shift1st', //string
         'shift2nd', //string
      ],
      'shift4rd', //string
      'shitf5th', //string
   ],
   'shift11th' => [
      'shift10th', //string
      'shift9th' => [
         'shift7th', //string
         'shift8th', //string
      ],
   ],
   'shift12th', //string
];
```

The point is to return and remove the end element in a recursive way since the array can have many (theatrically unlimited) dimensions. I've named the string and keys in the order i figured i needed to shift.

---

I have tried to replicate a function but it aint working because array_shift is returning the element and not the array it makes it difficult to recurse the dimension with an function. This doesn't work and keeps returning me `shift1st` (that i expect) but the array stays the same and is not shifted.

```
function array_shift_recursive(array $array) {
  // recurse 1st child if it's array
  if( !empty($array) && is_array(reset($array)) ){

    return array_shift_recursive(reset($array));
  }
  //shift element from current array.
  else{
    return array_shift($array);
  }
}
```

I know it must be something about reference. Knowing how reference works i still have to learn how and when to exploit it. this said, little reminder that array_shift(&$array); argument is natively passed by reference.

I found a way to make it happening by switching the value to false and then filter the array for empty element (that false is evaluated as) but this seems (is to me way too much) long and inefficient. read below if you like but the point is to avoid doing that ;)

```
function array_filter_recursive(array $array, $filter = null) {
  foreach( $array as &$v ){
    if( !empty($v) && is_array($v) ){
      $v = array_filter_recursive($v, $filter);
    }
  }
  return array_filter($array, $filter);
}

function isnot_empty(&$v) {
  if( !empty($v) ){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function turn_false(array $array = []) {
    foreach( $array as $k => &$v ){
      if( !empty($v) && is_array($v) ){
        $array[ $k ] = turn_false($v);
        break;
      }
      else{
        $array[ $k ] = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return $array;
  }
```

and then i can do

```
//This for now gives me the element i'm looking for as expected
$shifted=array_shift_recursive($array);

/** @TODO : get rid of this to remove the shifted element. */

//Replicate the top dimension path with a empty end element.
$empty=turn_false($array);

//Replace the array'S dimension with the empty dimension path 
$replaced=array_replace_recursive($array,$empty);

//Remove the empty element (as a bonus it also strip empty array left behind after removing the element)
$array=array_filter_recursive($replaced,'isnot_empty');


/* OR (how i use it to combine those 3 lines in (kind of) one)
$array = array_filter_recursive(
   array_replace_recursive(
      $array, turn_false($array)
   ), 'isnot_empty'
); 
 */
```

Comment: You overlook an important aspect of the original [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) PHP function: it takes as argument a reference to the array. The reference is needed to allow the function modify the array. Because the argument is not passed by reference, your function modifies a copy of the passed array.

Comment: whether you tried to use referenced `$array` in the `array_shift_recursive`

Comment: I knew it had something to do about references, like i knew array_shift takes the arguments as a reference (or it would not be able to modify the array while returning something else). Made me try a few things and got something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using the same logic than before except i use a foreach loop instead of reset to get the 1st element in the array. Reset only point the marker back and return the element at the pointer so i guess it was again making a copy.

If you want to skip ahead the empty dimension you can use array_filter to filter out the empty elements before rerunning the function.

Thanks to the commentators for the head up.

Consireding this input :

```
$array = [
   'abc' => [
      'def',
      'ghi' => [
         'jkl', 'mno'
      ],
   ],
   'pqr' => [
      'stu', 'vwx'
   ],
   'yz1',
   '234' => [ '456' => [ '789' ] ]
];
```

using this function :

```
function array_shift_recursive(array &$array) {
  foreach( $array as &$v ){
    if( (!empty($v) && is_array($v) ) ){
      return array_shift_recursive($v);
    }
    else{
      return array_shift($array);
    }
  }
}
```

we get the expected result seen with :

```
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //string(3) "def"
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //string(3) "jkl"
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //string(3) "mno"
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //array(0) { } //dimension 'ghi'
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //array(0) { } //dimension 'abc'
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //string(3) "stu"
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //string(3) "vwx"
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //array(0) { } //dimension 'pqr'
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //string(3) "yz1"
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //string(3) "789"
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //array(0) { } //dimension '456'
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //array(0) { } //dimension '234'
var_dump(array_shift_recursive($array)); //NULL // Array is empty (yay!)
```